# How to prove limit using epsilon-N definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to prove
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{n^2}{a^n} =0 \left ( a>1 \right ) $$

I tried using Bernoulli's inequality, but it's difficult to cancel out the term involing a.

Comment: Use the binomial theorem. You can then discard all the the terms except the one with $\binom{n}{3}$ by inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = 1 + b, b > 0$, then $a^n =(1+b)^n = 1 + nb + \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}b^2 + \dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}b^3+\cdots > \dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}b^3\implies \dfrac{n^2}{a^n} < \dfrac{6n}{(n-1)(n-2)b^3}$. From this it follows that the limit is zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot, btw how to choose the appropriate N?

Comment: You don't need to find $N$ because you use the squeeze lemma.

Comment: @LamHongYin you can find $N$from solving the expression, as you want to have "for $n>N$:  $\dfrac{6n}{(n-1)(n-2)b^3}<\epsilon$" then solve for $n<f(\epsilon)$ then let $N=f(\epsilon)$

Comment: Use the fact that $n-1>\frac  n 2$ and $n-2>\frac  n 2$ as long as $n >4$. Now you can easily find your $N$. @LamHongYin